# Difference between explaining and explanation

Tags: difference, gerunds

All verbs have -ing.
 Some verbs have its noun form that often ends with -ment, -ion, -ism and so on.

I want to know the difference.

> Your explanation was very good.
>   Your explaining was very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *-ing* form, as you say, can be made from more or less any verb. It refers to the **act** or **activity** of the verb.

So *Your explaining was very good* says that the **act of your explaining** was very good: perhaps you spoke well, perhaps the hearer was very much in need of an explanation. It does not directly say anything about the content of your explaining.

*Explanation* is an abstract noun derived from the same root as *explain*. (As you indicate, it is not predictable from either grammar or history whether this word exists or not: it just happens to, whereas *explainment* doesn't). It means **the content of your explaining**. *Your explanation was very good* says nothing about how well you spoke, or how much the hearer needed it explained: it says that the explanation you gave was clear and comprehensive, or perhaps had other virtues, such as being funny.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanation was very good.